# Changing the return order of captures in an LPeg pattern?

Tags: lua, lpeg

(I'm using Lua 5.2 and LPeg 0.12)

Suppose I have a pattern `P` that produces some indeterminate number of captures, if any, and I want to write create a pattern `Q` that captures `P` as well as the position after `P`--but for that position to be returned *before* the captures of `P`. Essentially, if `lpeg.match(P * lpeg.Cp(), str, i)` results in `v1, v2, ..., j`, then I want `lpeg.match(Q, str, i)` to result in `j, v1, v2, ...`.

Is this achievable without having to create a new table every time `P` is matched?

Mostly I want to do this to simplify some functions that produce iterators. Lua's [stateless iterator functions](http://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html) only get one control variable, and it needs to be the first value returned by the iterator function.

In a world that let people name the *last* arguments of a variadic function, I could write:

```
function pos_then_captures(pattern)
    local function roll(..., pos)
        return pos, (...)
    end
    return (pattern * lpeg.Cp()) / roll
end
```

Alas. The easy solution is judicious use of `lpeg.Ct()`:

```
function pos_then_captures(pattern)
    -- exchange the order of two values and unpack the first parameter
    local function exch(a, b)
        return b, unpack(a)
    end
    return (lpeg.Ct(pattern) * lpeg.Cp()) / exch
end
```

or to have the caller to `lpeg.match` do a pack/remove/insert/unpack dance. And as yucky as the latter sounds, I would probably do that one because `lpeg.Ct()` might have some unintended consequences for pathological but "correct" arguments to `pos_then_captures`.

Either of these creates a new table every time `pattern` is successfully matched, which admittedly doesn't matter too much in my application, but is there a way to do this without any pack-unpack magic?

I'm not too familiar with the internals of Lua, but it feels like what I really want to do is pop something from Lua's stack and put it back in somewhere else, which doesn't seem like an operation that would be directly or efficiently supported, but maybe something that LPeg can do in this specific case.

Comment: You can use `select` in the vararg function to get elements starting at an arbitrary point in the vararg argument `select(-1, ...)` is the last element. So `return select(-1, ...), ...` should prepend the final element onto the returned list though it won't remove that element from the end of the list but if your loop stops when it reaches its counter that shouldn't matter for this usage.

Comment: `select` is very interesting. Can't believe I missed that in the manual! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Match-time captures and upvalues get the job done. This function uses `Cmt` to ensure `pos` is set before sticking it in front of `pattern`'s captures in `pattern / prepend`.

```
Cmt = lpeg.Cmt
Cp  = lpeg.Cp

function prepend_final_pos(pattern)
    -- Upvalues are dynamic, so this variable belongs to a
    -- new environment for each call to prepend_final_pos.
    local pos

    -- lpeg.Cmt(patt, func) passes the entire text being
    -- searched to `function` as the first parameter, then
    -- any captures. Ignore the first parameter.
    local function setpos(_, x)
      pos = x

      -- If we return nothing, Cmt will fail every time
      return true
    end

    -- Keep the varargs safe!
    local function prepend(...)
      return pos, ...
    end

    -- The `/ 0` in `Cmt(etc etc) / 0` is to get rid of that
    -- captured `true` that we picked up from setpos.
    return (pattern / prepend) * (Cmt(Cp(), setpos) / 0)
end
```

Sample session:

```
> bar = lpeg.C "bar"
> Pbar = prepend_final_pos(bar)
> print(lpeg.match(Pbar, "foobarzok", 4))
7       bar
> foo = lpeg.C "foo" / "zokzokzok"
> Pfoobar = prepend_final_pos(foo * bar)
> print(lpeg.match(Pfoobar, "foobarzok"))
7       zokzokzok       bar
```

As intended, the actual captures have no influence on the position returned by the new pattern; only the length of the text matched by the original pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with your original solution w/o table captures nor match-time captures like this

```
function pos_then_captures(pattern)
    local function exch(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, ...)
        if a1 == nil then return end
        if a2 == nil then return a1 end
        if a3 == nil then return a2, a1 end
        if a4 == nil then return a3, a1, a2 end
        if a5 == nil then return a4, a1, a2, a3 end
        if a6 == nil then return a5, a1, a2, a3, a4 end
        if a7 == nil then return a6, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 end
        if a8 == nil then return a7, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6 end
        if a9 == nil then return a8, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7 end
        if a10 == nil then return a9, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8 end
        local t = { a10, ... }
        return t[#t], a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, unpack(t, 1, #t-1)
    end
    return (pattern * lpeg.Cp()) / exch
end
```

Following sample usage returns each matched 'a' with the end of match in front of it

```
local p = lpeg.P{ (pos_then_captures(lpeg.C'a') + 1) * lpeg.V(1) + -1 }
print(p:match('abababcd'))

-- output: 2       a       4       a       6       a
```

Comment: This simply postpones the creation of a table until the line `local a = { ... }`, which is really what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Take a look at [`select`](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua/blob/lua-5.1/src/lbaselib.c#L358) function source. It can trim `...` from the start, i.e. `return select(2, ...)` trims first argument and returns everything from the second one onwards, but it cannot trim final arguments (not that I know of). So I just unrolled `exch` for up to 10 args and impl rest of the cases with a table and using `unpack` and its optional 2nd and 3rd arguments.